# How can I fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' when process Bagging method

Tags: keras, lstm

I need to use Bagging method for LSTM, training on Time-Series data. I have defined the model base and use the KerasRegressor to link to scikit-learn. But have AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'loss'. How can I fix it?

Update: I have used the method of Manoj Mohan (at the first comment) and successful at the fit step. However, the problem comes as TypeError when I modify the class of Manoj Mohan to

```py
class MyKerasRegressor(KerasRegressor): 
    def fit(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        x = np.expand_dims(x, -2)
        super().fit(x, y, **kwargs)

    def predict(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = np.expand_dims(x, -2)
        super().predict(x, **kwargs)
```

It has solved the dimension problem of predict() which the same as the .fit(). 
The problem is:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-68d76cb73e8b> in <module>
----> 1 pred_bag = bagging_model.predict(x_test)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Full script:

```py
def model_base_LSTM():

    model_cii = Sequential()

    # Make layers
    model_cii.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=((1, 20))))
    model_cii.add(Dropout(0.4))

    model_cii.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    model_cii.add(Dropout(0.4))

    model_cii.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    model_cii.add(Dropout(0.4))

    model_cii.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    model_cii.add(Dropout(0.4))

    model_cii.add(Flatten())
    # Output layer
    model_cii.add(Dense(1))

    # Compile
    model_cii.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model_cii

model = MyKerasRegressor(build_fn = model_base_LSTM, epochs=100, batch_size =70)
bagging_model = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=model, n_estimators=10)
train_model = bagging_model.fit(x_train, y_train)

bagging_model.predict(x_test)

Output:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-68d76cb73e8b> in <module>
----> 1 pred_bag = bagging_model.predict(x_test)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the `model_base_LSTM()` method. Replace

```
return model
```

with

```
return model_cii
```

Fix for "Error when checking input", an extra dimension could be added like this. This also takes care of scikit-learn(2 dimensions) vs Keras LSTM(3 dimensions) problem. Create a subclass of KerasRegressor to handle the dimension mismatch.

```
class MyKerasRegressor(KerasRegressor):
    def fit(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        x = np.expand_dims(x, -2)
        return super().fit(x, y, **kwargs)

    def predict(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = np.expand_dims(x, -2)
        return super().predict(x, **kwargs)

model = MyKerasRegressor(build_fn = model_base_LSTM, epochs=100, batch_size =70)
```

Comment: Thank, but it lead to other problem on the array shape, ValueError: Error when checking input: expected cu_dnnlstm_38_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1162, 20). And I don't know where to fix it. do you know it?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the fix for the issue.

Comment: But there is another problem, the scikit learn fit API expects 2D array but keras LSTM expects 3D array.

Comment: Right, I still stuck with it

Comment: Updated the answer to handle this issue.

Comment: I have updated the issue when apply your code and modify it as the update in question, please see them, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer now. The 'return' statement was missing in the overridden functions. As return was missing, predict would return 'None' type which caused the problem.